# Convert string with different format to date

Tags: mysql, sql, date-conversion

I have a table with a string column (*varchar(200)*) that contain a date in different format. For example

```
may 24 1983 12:00AM
1981-01-13 00:00:00
1979-01-13 00:00:00:123
```

I want to convert this column in a date to extract year. How could i do? I have used STR_TO_DATE but don't work well. I must use SUBSTRING for each different format?

MySQL version 5.0.95

Comment: Bad schema. Bad. I would fix the data first (to a consistent convertible text value), then update the schema to use a real datetime column (and let the value be auto-converted or do whatever other magic is required for the conversion). Then use the standard data functions to extract the date. *This problem only exists because the database schema is broken.*

Comment: We are not discussing DB schema, which I agree with you it's really bad. The MAIN question is that I have this table as it is and i want to do this cleaning up job I must to convert these strings to datetime. How can you help? (With a constructive comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a trick for detecting a valid date on the [man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).  You can use it to determine whether a `STR_TO_DATE` format worked.

```
select foo,
    case when length(date(str_to_date(foo,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S"))) is not null then str_to_date(foo,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S")
        when length(date(str_to_date(foo,"%b %d %Y %h:%i%p"))) is not null then str_to_date(foo,"%b %d %Y %h:%i%p")
    end as newdate
from my_table
```

Put one format for everyone you're expecting.  Test like crazy.

Good luck.

(Oh, and congrats for trying to cleanup a bad schema!)

Comment: Do you wanna know the further complication? Abbreviations months name are not in English! Do you advise me to do a clean up of abbreviations (eg Italian - English gen = jan)?

Comment: If the abbreviations are in a bunch of different languages, then standardizing them will help.  If they're in one (say, Italian), I would wonder if changing the default language in mysql would cover it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do this using a server side language, perhaps PHP and use `strotime` to generate a pretty date.

Otherwise, the only other option I see is to start writing `CASE`s to read possible formats, and output using `DATE_FORMAT`. Perhaps something like:

*Pseudo-code* (for case may 24 1983 12:00AM)

```
CASE
    WHEN col (after first space is some digit) 
        AND (after second space is 4 digits)
        AND (after third space has 'AM' or 'PM')
    THEN
        DATE_FORMAT(col, '%....')
```

You can also trying using `REGEXP` to for pattern matching.