# Search a date range in a textfield

Tags: php, mysql

I have a *text field* in a MYSQL database with contain dates like `01/01/2014`, `06/2014` and `2014`

I'm like to perform searches like `dd/mm/aaaa`, `mm/aa` or `aaaa` in ranges.

Examples:

> 01/01/2013 to 011/01/2014

or

> 08/2013 to 09/2014

or

> 2013 to 2014

Any help to create mysql query?

Comment: sounds like the db structure is wrong.

Comment: simplify your db structure

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734054/convert-string-with-different-format-to-date

Comment: Hello. All dates are on a TEXT FIELD. Like: 

[02/2013, 03/2013, 01/01/2014]

Comment: Use datetime instead of text field. Then you can simplify your queries.

Comment: So some dates don't even have days or months?

Comment: Exactly, some date haven't day or month and i can have combination comma separated into a text field: [2013, 02/2014]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use between clause in your query `fieldname BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '011/01/2014'`

OR

```
SELECT * FROM theTable 
WHERE 
  fieldname >= '01/01/2013' AND fieldname <= '011/01/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

> After typing it in , I felt this probably is not a complete solution however I will leave it here .

My solution would be to modify your table structure .

Say your column holding those dates is : `date_in_text_format` . You could have additional column , say :

```
`date_in_mysql_date_format` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```

Now whenever you put a date in your `date_in_text_format` column :
Parse the date and put it into your `date_in_mysql_date_format` column as well .

When parsing , if `dd` is not available consider it `01` and if `mm` is not available consider it as `01` .

Now use your `date_in_text_format` column for display purposes .

And use your `date_in_mysql_date_format` for search purposes .

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your date / time format on the fly with mysql functions setting up an alias like this:

```
 SELECT *, 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(datestart,'%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s')) as conv_datestart, 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(dateend,'%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s')) as conv_dateend 
 FROM `theTable` 
 WHERE `fieldname` 
 LIKE 'WHATEVER' 
 HAVING (yourdate <= `conv_dateend` AND yourdate >= `conv_datestart`) 
 ORDER BY `conv_datestart` ASC 
 LIMIT 0,1;
```

But your first of all have to adapt this to your datetime-format. This is a bit dirty and ignores proper storing in mysql of a datetime-format, but it does the job.