# update mysql char data type to date with two format data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, formatting

i have a column with 'char' data type with two format records like this,

```
my_char_column
2030-05-12
2/8/2017
2012-12-13
```

the problem i want to change type data to 'date' with 'Y-m-d' format like this,

```
my_char_column_new
2030-05-12
2017-08-02
2012-12-13
```

i have tried to use this query but doesn't work

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_char_column = DATE_FORMAT(my_char_column,'%Y-%m-%d') where my_char_column LIKE'%/%'
```

Comment: Does all date only have these two formats?

Comment: yes, just two formats

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734990/8364246

Here is my way:
What you need here is some kind of condition check that can choose between two possibilities, IFNULL will serve that purpose. DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_char_column, '%Y-%m-%d') this convert "2030-05-12" this type of date, while DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_char_column, '%d/%m/%Y') will convert "2/8/2017" this type of date to the format you want i.e. %Y-%m-%d.

```
select IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_char_column, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(my_char_column, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) from your_table;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's not change my format date. are you have idea to select only like '2/8/2017' format ? i will change to 'y-m-d' format first before change the type data.

Comment: You can use a script in php or python to read columns one by one, then split the columns with '/', if the size of array thus created is more than one, the means the date is of "2/8/2017" format. Then you can combine it back to "2017-8-2" format. Then all the columns will be converted to same format. Then you can directly use STR_TO_DATE() function to convert string to date, or you can use your script only to convert string to date and insert back to table.

Comment: yes, i was thinking about that. I just try to find more eficient way to do that because i have 27530 record to change it. Thnks for your time.